# printf to console from various tasks

Tags: queue, printf, mutex, vxworks

I use VxWorks on an MCU and my application has various tasks that print out messages at different timing.

For example, considering I have 3 different tasks:
Task1 prints "Hello there"
Task2 prints "How are you"
Task3 prints "Doing"

When I open Tera Term, there will be a mess of printings, sometimes it could be a messed up message such as "Hello how there you Doing are" or something like that.
I wonder - if one implements an application that has many tasks that run in parallel and print various data out for debugging. There is a need to implement a queue for the printings? Or maybe to use a Mutex or something to synchronize the mass of data which is printed out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mutex would most certainly work. But it is not the real-time way to do it as it might lead to priority inversions. Also the time it takes to print characters on a slow serial channel is quite significant, it might mess the timings of your threads.

VxWorks offers a logging utility: [logLib](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/%7Ecourses/ee8205/Data-Sheets/Tornado-VxWorks/vxworks/ref/logLib.html)

Basically, it has its own low priority task. You pass messages to be prınted to said task and it prints them whenever it finds the CPU time. Printed messages are not interrupted, as they all are printed within the same task.

A side note would be starvation. If other threads occupy the CPU all the time, logTask will not be able to print the messages as it can acquire the CPU due to its low priority.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Do you know what happens if the queue/buffer which logLib uses is getting fulled and no one prints it out? assuming I use an uART channel for my printings, what happens when there is no TeraTerm open and the queue is not printed out to the screen, will logLib flushes out the buffer/queue when it is getting full?

Comment: With a serial channel, there is no way of knowing if there is someone listening on the other end. For any print to sysout from any source, CPU will simply pass output to related peripheral. On other words, you not listening will not stop the CPU from printing lines.